# Windows 10 Phone Locks Up / Freezes and Shows incorrect Time

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I have a weird issue with my windows phone (Windows Phone 10 / Microsoft branded hardware).

My phone is locking up / freezing.

This happens when I unplugging the phone from a computer (variety of windows 10 computers) and the phone goes to a standby state (black screen with only time showing). It doesn't happen every time I unplug the phone from a computer, but it happens about 70-80% of the time.

I can see the time on the phone, other than that it is a black screen. The time on the phone is frozen at the time that the phone locked up.

My only way around this is to hold down the power button until the phone resets. Sometimes this solves the issue. Sometimes the issue happens again as soon as the phone goes back to its black screen/only clock showing/stand-by state.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing hard reset (Settings - System - About - [Reset your phone]) or use [Device Recovery Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq) to update software image and reinstall OS.
Mind that this will reset all your phone settings so make sure you backup.